# deploy multiple laravel projects in apache virtual hosts

Tags: laravel, apache, deployment, production

I have two laravel projects, I deploy on VPS, then I configure the apache virtual host for each project in my /etc/apache2/sites-available.

example:

**project1.conf:**

```
Listen 8999
NameVirtualHost *:8999
<VirtualHost *:8999>
    ServerName project1.test
    ServerAlias www.project1.test
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/data/project1/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php   
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/data/project1/public/">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all 
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**project2.conf**

```
Listen 8998
NameVirtualHost *:8998
<VirtualHost *:8998>
    ServerName project2.test
    ServerAlias www.project2.test
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/data/project2/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
   
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/data/project2/public/">
         #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         #Order allow,deny
         Allow from all 
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in my /windows/system32/drivers/etc/host, I have already made a host for each project.

but I have a problem, which is when I open the first project in the browser and log in, then at the same time I open the second project and login too, when the first project is refreshed, it returns to the login page. Why did it happen ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing it the hard way, you can try to use Laravel Valet, which allows you to link your site to a domain like localhost.test and localhost2.test. It takes care of all virtual host configuration.